# How to write a private method that returns True for certain peramaters?

Tags: java, methods, boolean, private-methods

So the exact wording is, 
"Write a private method isValid(aRating) that returns true if the given rating is valid, which is between 1-10."

```
private void isValid(aRating)
{

}
```

What Goes in the Method above in order to return a true value if given rating is valid, Validity meaning a number 1-10.

This is what i attempted, the instructor wants it the "proper way" This is just an example of what i attempted at, It is a different program completely.(Ignore if confusing).

```
private void isValid(int hour,  int minute) 
{
    if (hour >= 0 && hour <=23) 
    {
        System.out.println("Hour is valid");
        hourIsValid = true;
    } 

    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Hour is not valid");
        hourIsValid = false;
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Would this be correct

```
    private boolean isValid(int aRating)
{                     
     if (aRating >= 1 && aRating <= 10)
         return true;
     else
         return false;
}
```

Comment: please restate your question. it is very unclear.

Comment: Formatting your code will make it easier for other people (and you) to read it, which means people will generally answer faster.

Comment: Okay i Reformatted the question, and the code is only an example of what i attempted at, it has nothing to do with the question, except showing how i cannot do it.

Comment: On an unrelated note, a system exit value of `0` generally indicates success. If you *are* going to just kill the program, you should exit with any value in the range 1-255 (like `System.exit(1);`).

Comment: Do the numbers 1-255 matter? Do they have different attributes or are they all just the same.

Comment: @Burninfate - The only generally agreed on exit code standard is that `0` is good and everything else is bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem demands a function that returns `true` under some conditions, so the signature cannot be

```
private void isValid(int aRating) {}
```

it needs a return type. Now, `true`'s type is boolean, so make it

```
private boolean isValid(int aRating) {
    return /* validity test here */;
}
```

Comment: @DannielFischer
`private boolean isValid(int aRating)
        {                 
             if (aRating >= 1 && aRating <= 10)
                 return true;
             else
                 return false;
         }`


Would this be the way to do it?

Comment: That would be _a_ way to do it. With a few hundred lines of code more below your belt, you'll prefer `return aRating >= 1 && aRating <= 10;` though, since `if (condition) return true; else return false;` can always be reduced to `return condition;`. Code formatting in comments is restricted, afaik.

Answer (score 2):

### Calling Private Methods

Calling a private method from a public one is exactly the same as calling any other method:

```
public void doStuff() {
    System.out.println("Stuff done.");
}

private void doOtherStuff() {
    System.out.println("Other stuff done.");
}

public void showHowItWorks() {
    doStuff();
    doOtherStuff();

    // or if you prefer this style:
    this.doStuff();
    this.doOtherStuff();
}
```

The important difference is that you can only call private methods from inside the class where they were defined:

```
class PublicExample {
    public static void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("Stuff done.");
    }
}

class PrivateExample {
    private static void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("Stuff done.");
    }
}

class Example {
    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        PublicExample.doStuff(); // Works
        PrivateExample.doStuff(); // Doesn't work (because it's private and defined in a different class)
    }
}
```

### Return Values

```
private void isValid(int hour,  int minute) {
    if (hour >= 0 && hour <=23) {
        System.out.println("Hour is valid");
        hourIsValid = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Hour is not valid");
        hourIsValid = false;
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that your program immediately dies if you input a bad hour or minute. What if I want to loop until I get a good input?

I think the main problem is that you don't know how to [return a value from a method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html). Here's an example of a function that always returns `true`:

```
public static boolean trueExample() {
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean returnValue = trueExample();
    System.out.println("trueExample() returned " + returnValue);
}
```

You can also make it more complicated:

```
/**
 * @return the input value minus one.
 */
public static int oneLess(int num) {
    return num - 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 10;

    // Print 10
    System.out.println(num);

    // Print 9
    num = oneLess(num);
    System.out.println(num);

    // Print 8
    num = oneLess(num);
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

Here's one that will return `true` if `num` is in the range 10-20 and `false` otherwise:

```
public boolean isValid(int num) {
    return num >= 10 && num <= 20;
}
```

This version does *exactly* the same thing, but you may find it easier to read since it's more explicit:

```
public boolean isValid(int num) {
    /* Numbers less than 10 are invalid */
    if(num < 10) {
        return false;
    }
    /* Numbers greater than 20 are invalid */
    else if (num > 20) {
        return false;
    }
    /* By process of elimination, everything else is valid */
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Let me know if that's not enough to help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you would call any normal method as long as the private method is visible to the public method.